# Run FXCop on console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fxcop

How to run FXCop on a C# console application? I can see only the exe in the bin folder but FXCop expects dll file for the project.

Do I need to change anything to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to project -> properties -> Code Analysis and check 'Enable Code Analysis on Build'. This runs Code Analysis, and not FxCop, but should functionally get you the same results.

Comment: If it doesn't run FxCop then it isn't the answer to the question How to run FxCop?

Comment: Code Analysis is a modified version of FxCop, which is integrated with Visual studio. Behind the scene it actually runs the FxCop command. It functionally does all you want from FxCop. You should check if it meets your requirements.

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/800973d2-4f85-43d3-ae89-5775b2e4918f/fxcop-vs-vs2012-code-analysis?forum=vsdebug. "Version considerations aside, FxCop and VS Code Analysis are essentially the same thing."